# Can Spree Commerce support "memberships"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm evaluating Spree Commerce for what my client needs. He wants to sell products on his page, and he also wants people to pay for an annual membership. They would pay the fee (could be a "product" in a shopping cart) then have their membership "active" for a year. They would be able to log into a "dashboard" page with their account and see that their membership status, either active or inactive. A user would not have to be an active member to purchase products, but active members would get special discounted pricing.

Please forgive my high level questions since I don't have much experience with Spree. But my questions are...

- Can I support memberships for users? If there's no actual specific Spree support for memberships, is it possible to perform some sort of after-purchase hook for a certain product to edit a user's account record to activate their membership?
- Does Spree support different price levels for different users? If I had a `User#active_member?` method or something similar, it would give them a certain discount. The admin would be able to edit member and non-member prices for each product.

I hope there is no need to reinvent the wheel and build a shopping cart system in Rails to support these features.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a 'Spree support' question than a programming question, but I'll give it a shot anyhow.

AFAIK, there is no built-in support for a purchased, time-limited membership, nor is there a 3rd party add-on (extension) to provide this at this time.

However, there are 'generic' membership extensions available (see [here](http://spreecommerce.com/extensions/338-promotion-roles-rule), for example), and it shouldn't be too hard to modify one of them to suit your situation.